# Proguard significantly increasing APK size in Android

Tags: android, proguard

I'm using the default settings in Eclipse to export my application and have Proguard obfuscate it.

The problem I'm having is that the exported APK is significantly larger than the APK I get when doing debug builds (~7MB instead of ~2MB).

If I look into the APKs I get the following:

(non-proguard)

```
/assets               (1.2 MB)
/META-INF             (42.3 KB)
/res                  (765.9 KB)
AndroidManifest.xml   (6.6 KB)
classes.dex           (416.1 KB)
resources.arsc        (49.5 KB)
```

(proguard)

```
/assets               (1.2 MB)
/hooks                (13.7 KB)
/info                 (240 bytes)
/logs                 (101.1 KB)
/META-INF             (496.6 KB)
/objects              (4.3 MB)               <-- main size difference
/refs                 (155 bytes) 
/res                  (777.4 KB)
AndroidManifest.xml   (6.6 KB)
classes.dex           (101.5 KB)
resources.arsc        (50.3 KB)
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong (it should be [getting smaller](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)!!!)?

Comment: Is it because it is bringing in whole librarys and obfuscating them even if your only using one method or one class from the library.

Comment: @Blundell Consider an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

classes.dex is significantly smaller so it looks like Proguard is working.

hooks, info, logs, objects, refs are Git directories – looks like you've mistakenly included them in your build.

Comment: You were, of course, correct that .git was getting included. Not sure how that happened. Thanks!